# How to give a variable for user-data-dir in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium Chrome driver using Python for some automation activities. I need to remember the logins and everything next time I'm starting the code and I'm using the options with user-data-dir for this.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=cookiename")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("site name")
```

Here is how my code looks like. The first time I'm running it, a directory named cookiename gets created.
What I want is to set a variable instead of cookiename, for eg:

```
cookiename = cookiefolder
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=cookiename")
```

and the folder created should be cookiefolder. Is it possible? I can't implement it like this.
This existing method is kind of hardcoding isn't it?

Comment: Are you want to save the browser cookie which is launched from selenium?

Comment: No, I have already done it, but right now I'm almost hardcoding the name of the directory where you can find the user-data, I want to use a variable for that.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually simple,

```
cookiename=cookiefolder

options.add_argument("user-data-dir="+cookiename)
```

basic python stuff